# PhoneGap: media.startRecord() not working in cordova-1.6.1

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I'm trying to record a sample audio with phoneGap, but with no success.

What I do is pretty simple, according to the documentation:

```
<script>
var media = null;

function record(){
   media = new Media("audio.wav");
   media.startRecord();
}
</script>
```

The "audio.wav" exists in my "www" folder and is an empty wav file.
Whenever this code block runs, I get this console error:

```
 - ERROR: Method 'create:withDict:' not defined in Plugin 'Media'

 - FAILED pluginJSON = {"className":"Media","methodName":"create","arguments":["INVALID","952d1fe0-5ec7-5e48-d68a-74cc979878b5","audio.wav"]}
```

Even with that error, the recording supposedly continues. But when I try to play the recording, I watch the media object at the debugger and I see '_duration : -1'

A different error appears when I try to debug the application on an actuall iPhone device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the problem was that even thought I correctly created the file on the root directory as you depict, I couldn't access it later on, even though I got it's URI (File not found for some reason, on the same directory the file was created a second ago!!!!). 
So I found out (not the easy way..) that I have to access it via `"documents://"`. So when I create a new Media I do something like :

`var mediaFile = new Media ("documents://"+audioFileName).`

If I had done "`var mediaFile = new Media(fileURI_I_Just_Created)` It would say that file does not exist!!!! (gotta love phoneGap!)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a blank wav file in the root directory, not the www folder. One of the ways you can get the root directories URI is by using the method [toURI()](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileEntry).

This is what the URI will look like:

```
file:///data/some/com.stack.overflow/
```

Below is an example of how you can create a blank wav file in the root directory:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
  window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
  fileSystem.root.getFile("blank.wav", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
}
```

Note:

> ```
> create: Used to indicate that the file or directory should be created, if it does not exist. (boolean)
> exclusive: By itself, exclusive has no effect. Used with create, it causes the file or directory creation to fail if the target path
> ```
>
> already exists. (boolean)